# ASUS F1A75 - M Motherboard. No Signal From HDMI Port?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hdmi, dvi

I have the above motherboard that had a DVI port and a HDMI port.
The DVI port outputs fine, but my HDMI port is not working?

I am running windows 8 and the PC is going through my Denon AVR X2000, which is connected to my Sony 55 inch LED. The resolution is 1920 x 1080.

Is there anything that I can do to force this through the HDMI port? Like in the BIOS?

Can anyone give me any pointers here? I am a little bit of a noob here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably a hardware failure and you have no chence to fix it, except if you buy a new motherboard. But if you want to be sure before a pay, try to boot this with an ubuntu pendrive/livecd and check if works with that. But don't have big hopes.